# Tornado custom error handler for Static file

Tags: python, tornado

How can I show custom 404 error page for static files?

in my current application handler I have added last pattern as follows

```
[
    (r'/(favicon.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": mypath}),
    (r'/foo',FooHandler),
    (r'/bar',BarHandler),
    (r'/(.*)',ErrorHandler),
]
```

and this is my error handler

```
class ErrorHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self,d):
        self.status_code = 404
        self.show404(d)
```

If I visit `http://localhost/abc` I am getting my custom 404 page

but if I try to get `http://localhost/static/abc.js` I'm getting the ugly error like below

```
line 2286, in validate_absolute_path
raise HTTPError(404)
HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

Is there any way to get this working? How can I show my custom error page for static files

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky; you need to subclass StaticFileHandler and override its write_error method, then install that class with static_handler_class Application setting.